# Mark or remove partly duplicate lines in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

Let's say i have a file like this opened in Notepad++:

```
email@address.com:word1
email@address.com:word2
email@address.com:word3
email@address1.com:word4
email@address2.com:word5
email@address3.com:word6
email@address3.com:word7
```

As you can see lines 1, 2, 3 and 6, 7 are duplicate before the ":". Is there any regex i can use to mark or remove all lines that are duplicate before the ":"?

Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Caution: this will only work on a sorted file.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^([^:]+:).+\R(?:.*?\1.+(?:\R|$))+`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
  ([^:]+:)      # group 1, 1 or more NOT colon followed by a colon (i.e. email address)
  .+            # 1 or more any character but newline
  \R            # any kind of linebreak (ie. \r, \n, \r\n)
  (?:           # start non capture group
    .*?         # 0 or more any character, not greedy
    \1          # backreference to group 1 (email address)
    .+          # 1 or more any character but newline
    (?:\R|$)    # non capture group, a ine break or end of line
  )+            # group  may appear 1 or more times
```

**Result for given example:**

```
email@address1.com:word4
email@address2.com:word5
```

Comment: @ReneeDeBock: You're welcome, glad it helps.