# For eliminate the lines with Duplicate URLs at the beginning of the line

Tags: notepad++, regex

Before:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Led_Zeppelin - Led Zeppelin - Stairway To Heaven 2
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Led_Zeppelin - Led Zeppelin - Stairway To Heaven 1 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dire_Straits - Dire Straits - Sultans Of Swing #1 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dire_Straits - Dire Straits - Sultans Of Swing #2
```

After:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Led_Zeppelin - Led Zeppelin - Stairway To Heaven 2
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dire_Straits - Dire Straits - Sultans Of Swing #1
```

Comment: No OS stated: Linux; The right tool for the task: Use `sort -u` or `uniq` from the command line. Similar - https://www.google.se/search?q=powereshell+uniqe

Comment: @Hannu: The lines are not strictly duplicate, only the URL part.

Comment: sort can be run on only a single or a few select "fields", e.g.e separated by spaces

Comment: Are the duplicate lines always one under the other?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mark or remove partly duplicate lines in Notepad++](https://superuser.com/questions/1387677/mark-or-remove-partly-duplicate-lines-in-notepad)

Comment: Do you want to compare only URL or URL + band name or URL + band name + song title?

Comment: I dont know if my solution is Correct with NotePad++:
- Select menu TextFx in notePad++ All Text 
- With TextFx Sort Ascending 
- With TextFx Sort Case Insensive 
- With TextFx Delete Duplicate Line 

Find Regex:    ^(.+? - ).+\R(?:\1.+\R?) 
Replace With:  \2

Answer (score 0):

This Replace dialog will do what is required:

Find what: `(https.+?) (.+?)\r\n\1.*?\r\n`
Replace with: `\1 \2\r\n`

---

[image]

---

Explanation:

- `()` - group
- `.+?` - any character string of at least one character, the `?`
  means non-greedy
- `\1` - the first matched group
- `\r\n` - carriage-return and line-feed, which is the end-of-line
  for Windows (for Linux use `\n`)

Note that for this to work, the last URL line must terminate with an
end-of-line.

Reference :
[Notepad++ User Manual](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/searching/).